# VSCode LiveServer and JavaScript Code Execution

Tags: javascript

I am using Visual Studio code and I already Install LiveServer to run JavaScript code. But Javascript code is not running in Live Server, Only HTML code is running and displays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purpose of LiveServer extension for VSC is to expose your workspace directory into `localhost:5000` with `index.html` (if exists) as entrypoint. If you want to execute any JavaScript through LiveServer you need to implement it first within your HTML file with script tags in the `head` or `body` element.

```js
// this is my main.js located in scripts catalog
document.getElementById("script").innerHTML = 'Hello World'
```

```html
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<h1 id="script"></h1>
```